# Library loaded using dlopen will not dlclose

Tags: c++, linux, dlopen

I am having trouble figuring out how to accomplish the following thing:

```
  1) Load in a library from libraryA.so,
  2) Call the 'main' function
  3) Unload the library.
```

Specifically, I cannot get step 3 to run reliably.

My library libraryA was compiled like this:

```
  g++ libraryA.c -o libraryA.so -shared -llibraryB
```

Here is what happens when I load libraryA:

```
  void* libA = dlopen("./libraryA.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_DEEPBIND)
```

The above command loads in libraryA from "libraryA.so", which in turn loads libraryB from "/usr/local/lib/libraryB.so".

However, there seems to be a cyclic dependency between libraryA and libraryB. (Perhaps due to the use of virtual functions.) Running with the option "LD_DEBUG=bindings" shows things like:

```
  binding file ./libraryA.so [0] to /usr/local/lib/libraryB.so [0]: normal symbol `_ZN55ArrayLJKiLi1EFD2Ef'
  ...
  binding file /usr/local/lib/libraryB.so [0] to ./libraryA.so [0]: normal symbol `_ZN55ArrayIKiLi1EED1Ev'
```

Because of this cyclic dependency, libraryA will not load when I call dlclose. Are there any ways around this? Is there anyway I can force a library along with all of the dependencies it pulled in automatically to be unloaded together?

Thank you very much,

Patrick

Comment: i guess you need to dlclose the other library first.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Actually I have not tried it. Because libraryB is not under my control, and I don't have a pointer to it. Is that a direction that I should look into?

Comment: so, try to dlopen B and then dlopen A. then you can try to dclose both of them.